# Java Gui Layout - which one does this use?

Tags: java

What layout does this java project use? I am confused on which layout it uses. I thought it was a BoxLayout because of the spacing between the columns. Any help? 
The main problem i am having is in the second picture, with the crn, coursenumber, etc...  how do i align text below that in same columns. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I'd actually say it's a `JTable`

Comment: Possibly [`GridBagLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).